# operator << in c#

Tags: c#, operators

i couldn't understand this code in c#

```
int i=4 
int[] s =new int [1<<i]; 
Console.WriteLine(s.length);
```

the ouput is 16 
i don't know why the output like that?

Answer (score 7):

[bit shift operator](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/CSharpShiftOperators.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

From documentation

> If first operand is an int or uint
>   (32-bit quantity), the shift count is
>   given by the low-order five bits of
>   second operand.
>
> If first operand is a long or ulong
>   (64-bit quantity), the shift count is
>   given by the low-order six bits of
>   second operand.
>
> Note that i<<1 and i<<33 give the same
>   result, because 1 and 33 have the same
>   low-order five bits.

This will be the same as 2^( *the actual value of the lower 5 bits* ).

So in your case it would be **2^4=16**.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you mean `i` in place of `r`...

`<<n` means "shift left by n* bits". Since you start with 1=binary 00...00001, if you shift left 4 times you get binary 00...10000 = 16 (it helps if you are familiar with binary arithmetic - otherwise "calc.exe" has a binary converter).

Each bit moves left `n` places, filling (on the right) with 0s. *=note that `n` is actually "mod 32" for `int`, so (as a corner case) 1 << 33 = 2, not 0 which you might expect.

There is also `>>` (right shift), which moves for the right, filling with `0` for `uint`s and +ve `int`s, and `1` for -ve `int`s.

Answer (score 0):

<< is the left shift operator

```
x << y
```

means shift x to the left by y bits.

3 is 0011, 3<<1 is 0110 which 6.

It's usually used to multiply by 2 (shifting to the left is multiplying by 2)

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, << is the left shift operator.  In your particular example, the array size is being defined as a power of 2.  The value 1 shifted left by some number is going to be 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, ...